# Why did I get an error "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"

Tags: javascript

I have a question for the below code. I get an error：app.js:141 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

```js
const cartDOM = document.querySelector(".cart__center");

    addToCart({ title, price, image, id }) {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add('cart__item');
    
        div.innerHTML = `<img src=${image} alt="">
        <div>
          <h3>${title}</h3>
          <h3 class="price">$${price}</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span data-id=${id}>`;
    
        cartDOM.appendChild(div);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us where 'cartDOM' is defined?

Comment: Please see update, thank you

Comment: The code is formatted incorrectly...

Comment: This definitely doesn't have a [example]. What is known is that `querySelector` can't find such an element...

Comment: thank you for your logic, i figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing that error because

```js
const cartDOM = document.querySelector(".cart__center");
```

Is being resolved as `null`, which means that an element couldn't be found in the document, by using your provided selector `".cart__center"`.

This might happen either because:

- The element doesn't match your selector criteria. Maybe instead of a class name, it's an id, or something else?
- The element is not in the DOM at the moment to execute that `querySelector()`, maybe it hasn't been loaded/rendered yet.

Unfortunately there aren't any more details provided about the issue, which would be useful to suggest a solution.

So I can only hope that at least I've provided some useful insight, and I'd suggest you to check the logic of your application to find the best way to fix it.